# Sed keep digit and discard extension

Tags: sed

I have a file with a lines that header contains the following pattern (tab separated)

```
1.mapped.bam 2.mapped.bam 3.mapped.bam ....
```

I would like

```
SAMPLE_1 SAMPLE_2 SAMPLE_3 .....
```

I have tried:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9])(.mapped.bam)/SAMPLE_\1/g
```

but got

```
1SAMPLE_1 2SAMPLE_2 3SAMPLE_3 ???
```

Comment: `sed -E 's/([0-9]+)\.mapped\.bam/SAMPLE_\1/g'` should work. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/0PiYXC).

Comment: Great works well !!!

Comment: though the suggested solution is better, I wonder why you got that output, the given command produces desired output for me on `GNU sed 4.2.2`

Comment: Could you please explain why you got that output? It seems there is some other piece of code you have not shared. If the solution below works, please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following POSIX ERE solution:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+)\.mapped\.bam/SAMPLE_\1/g'
```

An equivalent BRE POSIX solution is

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]*\)\.mapped\.bam/SAMPLE_\1/g'
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/0PiYXC)

Here,

- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1 (later referred to with `\1` placeholder from the RHS, replacement pattern): one or more digits
- `\.mapped\.bam` - a literal `.mapped.bam` substring.

Note that in both POSIX BRE and ERE dots outside of bracket expressions must be escaped to match literal dots, and capturing parentheses must be escaped in POSIX BRE flavor.